# why disabled links still clickable?

Tags: html, css

I have tried multiple inputs to make disabled links not clickable, but I'm still not able to disable said link from being, well, unclickable. I was able to make the cursor not-allowed when it hovers over said disabled link, but it's obviously still clickable. I have followed a few links like this [one](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-disable-links/) and this [sample](https://codepen.io/newbee1/pen/LYEVxNx), but nothing seems to work for me. I even checked under this site, but none of the samples I found helped. What am I doing wrong?

```css
 /***** whole navigation bar *****/
nav#prime {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14.75px;
}
nav#prime ul {  /*  whole <ul> tags under <nav> tag */
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
nav#prime li {  /*selects whole <li> tags under <nav> tag */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;  /*to provide boundry*/
}

/***** links *****/
ul#navbar a:link /* all normal, unvisited links under <ul> */ {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #0E0E10; /* jet black */
  color: #FFFAFA; /* Olde lace white */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 11px;
}
ul#navbar a:visited /* visited link */ {
  background-color: #F5F5F5; /* white smoke */
  color: #1A1110; /* licorice */
}
ul#navbar a:hover /* mouse over link, must come after <a:link> and <a:visited> */ {
  background-color: #242124; /* raiden */
  color: #FFFFF0; /* ivory */
}
ul#navbar a:active /* a link that's selected - must come after <a:hover> */ {
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  color: #808080;
}

/***** for all <button> tags *****/
button.dropbtn {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  font: inherit; /* Important for vertical-align on mobile phones */
  background-color: #0E0E10; /* jet black */
  color: #FFFAFA; /* Olde lace white */
  margin: 0; /* Important for vertical-align on mobile phones */
  padding: 5px 11px;
}

/***** submenu positioning *****/
#navbar ul {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 1;
  left: -99999em;
}

#navbar>li:hover>ul {
 
  position: absolute; /*to keep it under relative li*/
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#navbar>li:hover>li li:hover>ul {
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: 1px;
}

/***** first tier *****/
#navbar {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #0E0E10;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #0E0E10;
}
#navbar>li {
  float: left; /* brings sub elements under proper character */
}
```

```html
<nav id="prime">
    <ul id="navbar">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">The Desi Ghost Hunters
                <i class="caret-down"></i>
            </button>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li class="suboption"><a href="#" title="Siddharth Bantval">Siddharth Bantval</a></li>
                <li class="suboption"><a href="https://www.ikerjimenez.com/" target="_blank" title="REAL NAME: Iker Jiménez Elizari">Iker Jiménez</a></li>
                <li class="suboption"><a href="#" title="Gaurav Tiwari">Gaurav Tiwari <span class="cross">&#8225;</span></a></li>
                <li class="suboption"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC5RfSq8MS00LWofLPSKAnDA" target="_blank" title="Alberto del Arco">Alberto del Arco</a></li>
                <li class="suboption"><a href="#" title="Alexsander Myagchenkov">Alexsander Myagchenkov</a></li>
                <li class="suboption"><a href="http://chernobrov.narod.ru/" target="_blank" title="Vadim Chernobrov">Vadim Chernobrov <span class="cross">&#8225;</span></li>
                <li class="suboption"><a href="#" title="Meghna Porwal">Meghna Porwal</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I can’t see that you have followed the css tricks post as that has JavaScript. Please include the code you have tried, describe what is and isn’t working.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `pointer-events: none;` property to achieve this. You can still use event listeners to trigger actions if you need to, but regular clicking will not work!

Since `pointer-event: none;`disables all mouse functions, wrap the disabled link with a `div` tag, and then add the `cursor` input.

[MDN documentation for pointer-events property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

```css
/***** whole navigation bar *****/

nav#prime a {
  pointer-events: none;
}

nav#prime {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14.75px;
}
nav#prime ul {  /*  whole <ul> tags under <nav> tag */
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
nav#prime li {  /*selects whole <li> tags under <nav> tag */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;  /*to provide boundry*/
}

/***** links *****/
ul#navbar a:link /* all normal, unvisitied links under <ul> */ {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #0E0E10; /* jet black */
  color: #FFFAFA; /* olde lace white */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 11px;
}
ul#navbar a:visited /* visited link */ {
  background-color: #F5F5F5; /* white smoke */
  color: #1A1110; /* licorice */
}
ul#navbar a:hover /* mouse over link, must come after <a:link> and <a:visited> */ {
  background-color: #242124; /* raiden */
  color: #FFFFF0; /* ivory */
}
ul#navbar a:active /* a link that's selected - must come after <a:hover> */ {
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  color: #808080;
}

/***** for all <button> tags *****/
button.dropbtn {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  font: inherit; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
  background-color: #0E0E10; /* jet black */
  color: #FFFAFA; /* olde lace white */
  margin: 0; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
  padding: 5px 11px;
}

/***** submenu positioning *****/
#navbar ul {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 1;
  left: -99999em;
}

#navbar>li:hover>ul {
 
  position: absolute; /*to keep it under relative li*/
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#navbar>li:hover>li li:hover>ul {
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: 1px;
}

/***** first tier *****/
#navbar {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #0E0E10;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #0E0E10;
}
#navbar>li {
  float: left; /* brings sub elements under proper character */
}
```

```html
<nav id="prime">
    <ul id="navbar">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">The Desi Ghost Hunters
                <i class="caret-down"></i>
            </button>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li class="suboption"><a href="#" title="Siddharth Bantval">Siddharth Bantval</a></li>
                <li class="suboption"><a href="https://www.ikerjimenez.com/" target="_blank" title="REAL NAME: Iker Jiménez Elizari">Iker Jiménez</a></li>
                <li class="suboption"><a href="#" title="Gaurav Tiwari">Gaurav Tiwari <span class="cross">&#8225;</span></a></li>
                <li class="suboption"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC5RfSq8MS00LWofLPSKAnDA" target="_blank" title="Alberto del Arco">Alberto del Arco</a></li>
                <li class="suboption"><a href="#" title="Alexsander Myagchenkov">Alexsander Myagchenkov</a></li>
                <li class="suboption"><a href="http://chernobrov.narod.ru/" target="_blank" title="Vadim Chernobrov">Vadim Chernobrov <span class="cross">&#8225;</span></li>
                <li class="suboption"><a href="#" title="Meghna Porwal">Meghna Porwal</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: So I have placed the pointer even in the CSS code, but the not allowed cursor won't appear when hovering over disabled link. Why is that?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out .  . .

Comment: I am still having issues with the dropdown displayed. I managed to get it nested, but when it's hovered over, the main bar somewhat shifts and the dropdown is not of equal length. Here's what I have:
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.submenu { /* dropdown content hidden by defualt */
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown:hover .submenu {
  display: block;
  position: absolute; /*to keep it under relative li*/
}

Comment: I reckon your best bet is to submit another question with your updated code :)

Comment: I've posted another question here on this site. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73954979/navigations-dropdown-without-the-child-cominator