# navigations dropdown without the child cominator?

Tags: html, css

So I've recently asked a question here about having issues with why the content of my dropdown menu expanding pass the main navigation content. But I do not fully understand how the `child combinator` works under CSS, so I tried to do the CSS work without aforementioned child combinator. After several experiments, I've figured how to style the navigation without the use of CSS Selectors, but when the cursor hovers over the dropdown, it not only shifts, but the dropdown are not the same length.

```css
/***** whole navigation bar *****/

nav#nav-content {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  font-faimily: "Gill Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 13.7px;
}

nav#nav-content ul {
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav#nav-content {
  /*selects whole <li> tags under <nav> tag */
  position: relative;
  /*to provide boundry*/
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/***** all links *****/

ul#exo-menu a:link
/* all normal, unvisitied links under <ul> */

{
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #0E0E10;
  /* jet black */
  color: #FFFAFA;
  /* olde lace */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 6.5px 13px;
}

ul#exo-menu a:visited
/* visited link */

{
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  /* white smoke */
  color: #1A1110;
  /* licorice */
}

ul#exo-menu a:hover
/* mouse over link, must come after <a:link> and <a:visited> */

{
  background-color: #242124;
  /* raiden */
  color: #FFFFF0;
  /* ivory */
}

ul#exo-menu a:active
/* a link that's selected - must come after <a:hover> */

{
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  color: #808080;
}


/* disables links */

nav#nav-content div.cursor {
  /* Since pointer-event: none;disables all mouse functions, wrap  disabled link with a div tag, and then add the cursor input.*/
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

nav#nav-content a.disabledLink {
  pointer-events: none;
}


/***** all <button> tags *****/

button.dropbtn {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  font: inherit;
  /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
  background-color: #0E0E10;
  /* jet black */
  color: #FFFAFA;
  /* olde lace white */
  /* width: 100% */
  margin: 0;
  /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
  padding: 6.5px 13px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button.dropbtn:hover {
  background-color: #242124;
  /* raiden */
  color: #FFFFF0;
  /* ivory */
}

button.dropbtn:active {
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  color: #808080;
}


/***** submenu positioning *****/

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.submenu {
  /* dropdown content hidden by defualt */
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .submenu {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  /*to keep it under relative li*/
}
```

```html
<nav class="topnav" id="nav-content">
  <ul id="exo-menu">
    <li class="dropdown simple">
      <button type="button" onclick="togglefolder(&#39;folder0&#39;);" class="dropbtn main" aria-expanded="false">Main Investigators
                <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i>
            </button>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li class="option"><a href="https://thehauntedmuseum.com/" title="Zak Bagans" target="_blank">Zak Bagans</a></li>
        <li class="option"><a href="#" title="Nick Groff">Nick Groff</a></li>
        <li class="option"><a href="https://mediumcindykaza.com/" title="Cindy Kaza" target="_blank">Cindy Kaza</a></li>
        <li class="option">
          <button type="button" onclick="alert('Go to their link')" class="dropbtn" id="btnAlert">The Ghost Brothers
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i>
                    </button>
        </li>
        <li class="option"><a href="#" title="Aaron Goodwin">Aaron Goodwin</a></li>
        <li class="option"><a href="http://theparanormalist.org/" target="_blank" title="Jason Hawes">Jason Hawes</a></li>
        <li class="option"><a href="https://www.kimthehappymedium.com/" title="Kim Russo" target="_blank">Kim Russo</a></li>
        <li class="option"><a href="https://www.elizabethsaint.com/" title="Elizabeth Saint" target="_blank">Elizabeth Saint</a></li>
        <li class="option"><a href="#" title="K.D. Stafford">K.D. Stafford</a></li>
        <li class="option"><a href="https://www.darknessradio.com/" title="Dave Schrader" target="_blank">Dave Schrader</a></li>
        <li class="option"><a href="#" title="Billy Tolley">Billy Tolley</a></li>
        <li class="option"><a href="#" title="Jay Wasley">Jay Wasley</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown mega">
      <button type="button" onclick="togglefolder(&#39;folder0&#39;);" class="dropbtn main" aria-expanded="false" title="families who investigate unexplained phenomena, generally pertaining to ghosts">Paranormal Hunting Families
                <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i>
            </button>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li class="option">
          <div class="parafamily">
            <p class="para-paragraph-fam">Holzers</p>
            <a href="#" title="Professor Dr. Hans Holzer, Ph.D.">Dr. Hans Holzer <span class="cross">&#8225;</span></a>
            <div class="box">
              <span class="paraspouse">Spouses</span>
              <a href="https://alexandraholzer.com/" title="Alexandra Holzer" target="_blank">Alexandra Holzer</a>
              <a href="#" title="David Lawson">David Lawson</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="parafamily">
            <p class="para-paragraph-fam">Klinge</p>
            <div class="box">
              <span class="parasibs">Sibling</span>
              <a href="#" title="Barry Klinge">Barry Klinge</a>
              <a href="#" title="Brad Klinge">Brad Klinge</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="parafamily">
            <p class="para-paragraph-fam">Osbournes</p>
            <div class="box">
              <span class="parasibs">Sibling</span>
              <a href="#" title="Kelly Osbourne">Kelly Osbourne</a>
              <a href="#" title="Jack Osbourne">Jack Osbourne</a>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
              <span class="paraspouse">Spouses</span>
              <a href="https://www.sharonosbourne.com/" title="Sharon Levy" target="_blank">Sharon Levy-Arde</a>
              <a href="https://www.ozzy.com/" title="Ozzy Osborne" target="_blank">Ozzy Osborne</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="parafamily">
            <p class="para-paragraph-fam">Warren</p>
            <div class="box">
              <span class="paraspouse">Spouses</span>
              <a href="#" title="Edward Miney">Edward Warren Miney <span class="cross">&#8225;</span></a>
              <a href="#" title="Lorraine Warren">Lorrain Moran <span class="cross">&#8225;</span></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="parafamily">
            <p class="para-paragraph-fam">Zaffis</p>
            <div class="box">
              <span class="parasibs">Siblings</span>
              <a href="#" title="Aime'e Zaffis">Aime'e Zaffis</a>
              <a href="#" title="Chris Zaffis">Chris Zaffis</a>
            </div>
            <a href="https://www.johnzaffis.com/" title="John Zaffis" target="_blank">John Zaffis</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="option">
          <button type="button" onclick="togglefolder(&#39;folder0&#39;);" class="dropbtn previous">Former
                        <i class="caret-down"></i>
                    </button>
          <div class="parafamily">
            <p class="para-paragraph-fam">Lowe</p>
            <div class="box">
              <span class="parasibs">Siblings</span>
              <a href="#" title="John Lowe">John Lowe</a>
              <a href="#" title="Matthew Lowe">Matthew Lowe</a>
            </div>
            <a href="#" title="Rob Lowe">Rob Lowe</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown horizontal">
      <button type="button" onclick="togglefolder(&#39;folder0&#39;);" class="dropbtn  main-btn" aria-expanded="false" title="Best friends from Atlanta">The Ghost Brothers
                <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i>
            </button>
      <ul class="submenu simple">
        <li class="option"><a href="#Dalen" title="Dalen Spratt">Dalen Spratt</a></li>
        <li class="option"><a href="#JuwanMass" title="Juwan Mass">Juwan Mass</a></li>
        <li class="option"><a href="#">Marcus Harvey</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: The child combinator is actually simpler than just a space (descendant combinator), so I recommend spending the time to learn it instead of working around it when you might need it.

Comment: "dropdown are not the same length" , why would they be? The content is different lengths. The shift to the left occurs when the height of the dropdown exceeds the height of the viewport and the browser adds a scroll bar to accommodate this.

Comment: I like to explore different options. Besides, I'm trying to follow the example from W3Schools

Answer (score 0):

The shift to left happens because your dropdown menu is insanely **longer** than the `viewport`, so when it reaches the bottom of the page, the body `scrollbar` appears pushing things to the left. that's why it happens.

So to solve this, you can just give your dropdown specific `height` to prevent it from reaching the bottom of the page then set its `overflow` to auto so it has its own `scrollbar`.

I suggest you **do the same** with other dropdowns to avoid this issue if the screen (viewport) is shorter than the dropdown.

```
.submenu {
  /* dropdown content hidden by defualt */
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  
  max-height: 80vh;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

here is your full code in a snippet.

```css
/***** whole navigation bar *****/

nav#nav-content {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  font-faimily: "Gill Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 13.7px;
}

nav#nav-content ul {
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav#nav-content {
  /*selects whole <li> tags under <nav> tag */
  position: relative;
  /*to provide boundry*/
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/***** all links *****/

ul#exo-menu a:link
/* all normal, unvisitied links under <ul> */

{
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #0E0E10;
  /* jet black */
  color: #FFFAFA;
  /* olde lace */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 6.5px 13px;
}

ul#exo-menu a:visited
/* visited link */

{
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  /* white smoke */
  color: #1A1110;
  /* licorice */
}

ul#exo-menu a:hover
/* mouse over link, must come after <a:link> and <a:visited> */

{
  background-color: #242124;
  /* raiden */
  color: #FFFFF0;
  /* ivory */
}

ul#exo-menu a:active
/* a link that's selected - must come after <a:hover> */

{
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  color: #808080;
}


/* disables links */

nav#nav-content div.cursor {
  /* Since pointer-event: none;disables all mouse functions, wrap  disabled link with a div tag, and then add the cursor input.*/
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

nav#nav-content a.disabledLink {
  pointer-events: none;
}


/***** all <button> tags *****/

button.dropbtn {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  font: inherit;
  /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
  background-color: #0E0E10;
  /* jet black */
  color: #FFFAFA;
  /* olde lace white */
  /* width: 100% */
  margin: 0;
  /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
  padding: 6.5px 13px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button.dropbtn:hover {
  background-color: #242124;
  /* raiden */
  color: #FFFFF0;
  /* ivory */
}

button.dropbtn:active {
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  color: #808080;
}


/***** submenu positioning *****/

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.submenu {
  /* dropdown content hidden by defualt */
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  
  max-height: 80vh;
  overflow: auto;
}

.dropdown:hover .submenu {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  /*to keep it under relative li*/
}
```

```html
 <nav class="topnav" id="nav-content">
    <ul id="exo-menu">
      <li class="dropdown simple">
        <button type="button" onclick="togglefolder(&#39;folder0&#39;);" class="dropbtn main" aria-expanded="false">Main Investigators
                  <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i>
              </button>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li class="option"><a href="https://thehauntedmuseum.com/" title="Zak Bagans" target="_blank">Zak Bagans</a></li>
          <li class="option"><a href="#" title="Nick Groff">Nick Groff</a></li>
          <li class="option"><a href="https://mediumcindykaza.com/" title="Cindy Kaza" target="_blank">Cindy Kaza</a></li>
          <li class="option">
            <button type="button" onclick="alert('Go to their link')" class="dropbtn" id="btnAlert">The Ghost Brothers
                          <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i>
                      </button>
          </li>
          <li class="option"><a href="#" title="Aaron Goodwin">Aaron Goodwin</a></li>
          <li class="option"><a href="http://theparanormalist.org/" target="_blank" title="Jason Hawes">Jason Hawes</a></li>
          <li class="option"><a href="https://www.kimthehappymedium.com/" title="Kim Russo" target="_blank">Kim Russo</a></li>
          <li class="option"><a href="https://www.elizabethsaint.com/" title="Elizabeth Saint" target="_blank">Elizabeth Saint</a></li>
          <li class="option"><a href="#" title="K.D. Stafford">K.D. Stafford</a></li>
          <li class="option"><a href="https://www.darknessradio.com/" title="Dave Schrader" target="_blank">Dave Schrader</a></li>
          <li class="option"><a href="#" title="Billy Tolley">Billy Tolley</a></li>
          <li class="option"><a href="#" title="Jay Wasley">Jay Wasley</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown mega">
        <button type="button" onclick="togglefolder(&#39;folder0&#39;);" class="dropbtn main" aria-expanded="false" title="families who investigate unexplained phenomena, generally pertaining to ghosts">Paranormal Hunting Families
                  <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i>
              </button>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li class="option">
            <div class="parafamily">
              <p class="para-paragraph-fam">Holzers</p>
              <a href="#" title="Professor Dr. Hans Holzer, Ph.D.">Dr. Hans Holzer <span class="cross">&#8225;</span></a>
              <div class="box">
                <span class="paraspouse">Spouses</span>
                <a href="https://alexandraholzer.com/" title="Alexandra Holzer" target="_blank">Alexandra Holzer</a>
                <a href="#" title="David Lawson">David Lawson</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="parafamily">
              <p class="para-paragraph-fam">Klinge</p>
              <div class="box">
                <span class="parasibs">Sibling</span>
                <a href="#" title="Barry Klinge">Barry Klinge</a>
                <a href="#" title="Brad Klinge">Brad Klinge</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="parafamily">
              <p class="para-paragraph-fam">Osbournes</p>
              <div class="box">
                <span class="parasibs">Sibling</span>
                <a href="#" title="Kelly Osbourne">Kelly Osbourne</a>
                <a href="#" title="Jack Osbourne">Jack Osbourne</a>
              </div>
              <div class="box">
                <span class="paraspouse">Spouses</span>
                <a href="https://www.sharonosbourne.com/" title="Sharon Levy" target="_blank">Sharon Levy-Arde</a>
                <a href="https://www.ozzy.com/" title="Ozzy Osborne" target="_blank">Ozzy Osborne</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="parafamily">
              <p class="para-paragraph-fam">Warren</p>
              <div class="box">
                <span class="paraspouse">Spouses</span>
                <a href="#" title="Edward Miney">Edward Warren Miney <span class="cross">&#8225;</span></a>
                <a href="#" title="Lorraine Warren">Lorrain Moran <span class="cross">&#8225;</span></a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="parafamily">
              <p class="para-paragraph-fam">Zaffis</p>
              <div class="box">
                <span class="parasibs">Siblings</span>
                <a href="#" title="Aime'e Zaffis">Aime'e Zaffis</a>
                <a href="#" title="Chris Zaffis">Chris Zaffis</a>
              </div>
              <a href="https://www.johnzaffis.com/" title="John Zaffis" target="_blank">John Zaffis</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="option">
            <button type="button" onclick="togglefolder(&#39;folder0&#39;);" class="dropbtn previous">Former
                          <i class="caret-down"></i>
                      </button>
            <div class="parafamily">
              <p class="para-paragraph-fam">Lowe</p>
              <div class="box">
                <span class="parasibs">Siblings</span>
                <a href="#" title="John Lowe">John Lowe</a>
                <a href="#" title="Matthew Lowe">Matthew Lowe</a>
              </div>
              <a href="#" title="Rob Lowe">Rob Lowe</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown horizontal">
        <button type="button" onclick="togglefolder(&#39;folder0&#39;);" class="dropbtn  main-btn" aria-expanded="false" title="Best friends from Atlanta">The Ghost Brothers
                  <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i>
              </button>
        <ul class="submenu simple">
          <li class="option"><a href="#Dalen" title="Dalen Spratt">Dalen Spratt</a></li>
          <li class="option"><a href="#JuwanMass" title="Juwan Mass">Juwan Mass</a></li>
          <li class="option"><a href="#">Marcus Harvey</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```